# How can I implement firebase only once and use it in other scripts instead of initializing in every script I need it in javscript?

Tags: javascript, firebase

So I'm looking for a way to initialize Firebase in only one JavaScript file and then access firebase in other scripts to use it in there. Right now, in every script I use firebase in I have to initialize it which means I'm calling     `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);` in every script and I'm hoping I could maybe define it once and get it in every script that I need it in.

Comment: are u using webpack or something like that?

Comment: I am not using webpack.

Comment: check my answer, you can declare firebase as you custom global

Comment: So I don't have to have webpack to use your answer?

Comment: No, but you need some similar package manager, can you share more details about ur implementation so I can help u better?

Comment: I have Node obviously with its package manager but that's it

Comment: Oh yes, you can use it, maybe use require instead import and module.exports instead exports, that should do the trick :-) hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

require('firebase/firestore')
var config = {
  apiKey: process.env['FIREBASE_API_KEY'],
  authDomain: process.env['FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN'],
  databaseURL: process.env['FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL'],
  projectId: process.env['FIREBASE_PROJECT'],
  storageBucket: process.env['FIREBASE_STORAGE'],
  messagingSenderId: process.env['FIREBASE_MESSAGE_ID'],
  appId: process.env['FIREBASE_APP_ID'],
}

firebase.initializeApp(config)

export default firebase
```

On your index.js you require this file, then you import firebase on any file.. not need to init your app again